# Fldigi usb to db9

Tags: usb

Ubuntu 14.4.4. Yaesu FT-450D. Fldigi & flrig do not see the radio. I use a db9 to usb cable. I tested with rigctl and it did not see the rig. From the looks of the previous non-answered questions, nobody gives a &$#%. Just thought I'd try.

Answer (score 0):

been a while since I fought w/FLDigi and an adapter but I do remember I had to reinstall ALL the ax.25 apps [in the default Amateur Radio section of the default Repos] and I also installed "grig" [even though I did NOT use the grig program] so that may be worth trying.

Also, may be good to double check the radio "driver" support [since the radio you mentioned is popular it's probably well supported, then again, my Kenwood TS-2000 still, years out, is only in beta support for the "driver" (sorry forget the specific protocol, I'll try an find it]

GL and 73 de KE7TDY

oh, also, did you try using any other digital software, like WSJT or something to try to narrow down if it's the digital mode software [fldigi in your case] or the adapter [usb to db9] or something else?